# How to populate different FontAwesome icons to the WordPress category list using jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have the below WordPress categories list:

```
<ul class="fruits">
 <li class="fruit-cat fruit-cat-apple"><a href="#">
  <div>FA Apple Icon</div>
  <div>Apple</div>
 </a></li>
 <li class="fruit-cat fruit-cat-mango"><a href="#">
  <div>FA Mango Icon</div>
  <div>Mango</div>
 </a></li>
 <li class="fruit-cat fruit-cat-grape"><a href="#">
  <div>FA Grape Icon</div>
  <div>Grape</div>
 </a></li>
</ul>
```

I have used the below `WP Query` to get the above list:

```
$terms = get_terms('category', 'orderby=name');
 foreach ($terms as $term) :
  $termLink = get_term_link($term);
   echo '<ul>';
   echo '<li class="fruit-cat fruit-cat-' . $term->slug . '"><a href=' . esc_url($termLink) . '>
   <div><i class="fa fa-2x fa-user-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
   <div class="ml-2"><b>' . $term->name . '</b></div>
  </a></li>';
  echo '</ul>'
 endforeach;
```

I am creating two `<div>`'s in every `<li>` and, each `<li>` has its `category-slug` as the class names.
I have the list of 20+ categories in my WordPress.

I want to place different `FontAwesome` icons as per the category in the first `<div>`.
Since, each `<li>` has own class or can have ID, how do I change the `FontAwesome` tag / class as per the category, by using jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it myself using `switch` function:
My `WP Query` looks like this now:

```
$terms = get_terms('category', 'orderby=name');
 foreach ($terms as $term) :
  $termLink = get_term_link($term);
  switch ($term->slug) {
   case 'apple':
    $icon = 'cutlery';
    break;
   case 'mango':
    $icon = 'smile-o';
    break;
   case 'grape':
    $icon = 'frown-o';
    break;
    }
   echo '<ul>';
   echo '<li class="fruit-cat fruit-cat-' . $term->slug . '"><a href=' . esc_url($termLink) . '>
   <div><i class="fa fa-2x fa-'.$icon.'" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
   <div class="ml-2"><b>' . $term->name . '</b></div>
  </a></li>';
  echo '</ul>'
 endforeach;
```

Now, I have the above code generate this HTML:

```
<ul class="fruits">
 <li class="fruit-cat fruit-cat-cutlery"><a href="#">
  <div><i class="fa fa-cutlery" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
  <div>Apple</div>
 </a></li>
 <li class="fruit-cat fruit-cat-mango"><a href="#">
  <div><i class="fa fa-smile-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
  <div>Mango</div>
 </a></li>
 <li class="fruit-cat fruit-cat-grape"><a href="#">
  <div><i class="fa fa-frown-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
  <div>Grape</div>
 </a></li>
</ul>
```